# Gauss curvature of a fibre as a submanifold in a Riemannian warped product

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Consider the Riemannian warped product $M^{n+1}=I\times\mathbb{S}^n$ with metric
\begin{align}
g=dt\otimes dt+f(t)^2g_{\mathbb{S}^n}
\end{align}
where $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is some open interval and the warping function $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is smooth and positive. Fix a $t_0\in I$. Following O'Neill's terminology, I will call $\Sigma_0:=\{t_0\}\times\mathbb{S}^n$ a *fiber* of $M$. and view it as a Riemannian submanifold of $M$. Let me denote the induced metric as $g_0$. In this case, we have 
\begin{align}
g_0=f(t_0)^2g_{\mathbb{S}^n}
\end{align}
Denote the components of $g_0$ by $g_{ij}$.

After some computations, the second fundamental form of $\Sigma_0$ is given by 
\begin{align}
h_{ij}=\frac{f'(t_0)}{f(t_0)}g_{ij}
\end{align}
where $f'=\frac{df}{dt}$. I will omit $t_0$ in below. From this we deduce that

1. $\Sigma_0$ is totally umbilical.
2. The mean curvature is given by 
   \begin{align}
   H=\lambda_1+\cdots+\lambda_n=\frac{nf'}{f}
   \end{align}
3. The Gauss curvature is given by 
   \begin{align}
   K=\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n=\left(\frac{f'}{f}\right)^n
   \end{align}

On the other hand, since $g_0$ just a scalar multiple of the round metric, the fiber $(\Sigma_0,g_0)$ is just a round sphere of radius $f(t_0)$, and so we should have 
\begin{align}
K=\frac{1}{f^n}
\end{align}
instead.

> This thus yields two different answers for the Gauss curvature. Apparently something must be wrong. Hence I would like to know where is the error.

Any comment, hint and answer are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a term involving the intrinsic (Riemann) curvature of $M$.

Comment: More specifically, the intrinsic nature of the Gauss curvature is derived from the formula: $$ h_{ik}h_{jl} - h_{il}h_{jk} . = R_{ijkl} - \tilde{R}_{ijkl}, $$ where $R$ is the Riemann curvature of $\Sigma_0$ and $\tilde{R}$ is the Riemann curvature of $M$.